# Cannot Set 4 Byte Hardware Breakpoint Windbg

Tags: c++, debugging, reverse-engineering, windbg

I cannot set 4 byte read / write access hardware breakpoint using windbg.

```
0:000> dd 02e80dcf
02e80dcf  13121110 17161514 1a191800 1e1d1c1b
02e80ddf  011c171f c7be7df1 00000066 4e454900
```

Actually I have to check when the value **0x13121110** (at address 0x02e80dcf)is getting changed/overwritten by the program.

So When I'm trying to set a 4 byte write access hardware breakpoint @ **0x02e80dcf**, I'm getting **Data breakpoint must be aligned** Error.

```
0:000> ba w 4 02e80dcf
Data breakpoint must be aligned
                     ^ Syntax error in 'ba w 4 02e80dcf'
0:000> ba r 4 02e80dcf
Data breakpoint must be aligned
                     ^ Syntax error in 'ba r 4 02e80dcf'
0:000> ba w 1 02e80dcf
breakpoint 0 redefined
```

I'm able to set 1 byte write access breakpoint at the address, But it not getting triggered when the pointer @ address 0x02e80dcf is getting overwritten.

And also if anyone could suggest any other way to detect the address overwritten  thing would be really helpful.

**Note :** The problem I'm facing for a particular program. I'm able to set 4 byte hardware break point in the same debugging environment.

Comment: You have a C++ tag.  Where's the C++code?  All I see is conversation with WinDbg.

Comment: It was suggested by SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addresses must be aligned on a 4-byte boundary (or larger for 64-bit systems).

Any hex address ending in  0xf is not aligned to a 4-byte boundary.

There may be a restriction by WinDbg that data breakpoints are aligned to 4 or 8 byte boundaries.  You many need to use conditional break so that only the one byte is checked.

Comment: Thanks a lot!So I did something like, "ba w 4 02e80dcf-1", And it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

As a side note, this particular behavior is from the CPU architecture itself (not from the system or the debugger).

x86 and x86-64 (IA32 and IA32-e in Intel lingo) architecture use Drx (Debug Registers) to handle hardware breakpoints.

Dr7 LENn field will set the length of a breakpoint and Dr0 to Dr3 will hold the breakpoint addresses.

from `Intel Manual 3B - Chapter 18.2.5. "Breakpoint Field Recognition"`:

> The LENn fields permit specification of a 1-, 2-, 4-, or 8-byte range,
>   beginning at the linear address specified in the corresponding debug
>   register (DRn).

In the same chapter it is explicitly stated:

> Two-byte ranges must be aligned on word boundaries; 4-byte ranges must
>   be aligned on doubleword boundaries.

If you cover the desired address with a data breakpoint with a big enough length, then it will trap (breakpoint will be hit):

> A data breakpoint for reading or writing data is triggered if any of
>   the bytes participating in an access is within the range defined by a
>   breakpoint address register and its LENn field.

The manual then goes on giving a tip to trap on unaligned address and gives an example table:

> A data breakpoint for an unaligned operand can be constructed using
>   two breakpoints, where each breakpoint is byte-aligned and the two
>   breakpoints together cover the operand.

[image: Hardware brakpoints help table]